# PDF mimetype, is this a bug?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, mime-types

I'm uploading a pdf via a ASP.NET web form and checking it's MIME. Sometimes the MIME is reported as applicaton/pdf, not application/pdf. Is this a browser bug?  Why would application be spelled wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly a bug somewhere.  `applicaton` is not a valid [IANA-listed](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) mime directory.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a browser bug. Never rely on the data the client sends you - better call a local code that finds out the mime type for you.